# Compile error says 'assignment to read-only variable' when variable was not declared uniform

Tags: opengl, glsl, sfml

I am getting the following error in the fragment shader. I'm confused because the variable wasn't declared uniform.

To compile the shaders, I'm using SFML's `loadFromFile()` function.

My `.frag` shader

```
varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

uniform sampler2D uTexture;
uniform float uTime;

void main() {

    float coef = sin(gl_FragCoord.y * 0.1 + 1.0 * uTime);
    vTexCoord.y += coef * 0.03;
    gl_FragColor = vColor * texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoord);
```

My `.vert` shader

```
varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main() {

    vColor = gl_Color;
    vTexCoord = (gl_TextureMatrix[0] * gl_MultiTexCoord0).xy;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

Error message:

> 0:10(2): error: assignment to read-only variable 'vTexCoord'

Comment: It could be from `void main()`.  The `main` function returns an `int`.  Always.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but I don't understand how the two have anything to do with each other. Also from all the examples I've seen, in GLSL, main is declared void.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I believe `void main()` is the correct signature for a shader.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews In C++, sure, but not in GLSL.

Answer (score 2):

varying variable in a fragment shader are read-only, varying in a fragment shader means the vertex shader can pass different value through this variable to the fragment shader in contrast with uniform var which will get the same value. You need to introduce a local variable in your fragment shader main(), set its value as you want and use this local var to sample your texture.

Answer (score 0):

Varying variables are read-only. The definition of a varying variable is here-  https://thebookofshaders.com/glossary/?search=varying . But read-only does not mean the variables cannot be copied. Check Memory Qualifiers here-  https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Vertex_shader_i

```
varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

uniform sampler2D uTexture;
uniform float uTime;

void main() {

    float coef = sin(gl_FragCoord.y * 0.1      + 1.0 * uTime);
    vec2 c = vTexCoord; // assigned co-ordinates to a new variable here
    c.y += coef * 0.03;
    gl_FragColor = vColor * texture2D(uTexture, c); // implemented new variable here
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).